# using and declaring a custom WPF Page class in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'd like to create a custom WPF Page class that all of my Pages derive from:

```
public class CustomPage : Page
{
  // custom dependency props here...
}
```

I don't understand how to then create a new Page in my Visual Studio project and then have it use the Custom Page type. The problem is the root element in the Page's XAML. How do I declare it? This doesn't work:

```
<local:CustomPage 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
  x:Class="KinectLevelUp.CustomSwipe.Views.Page1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">

  <Grid>
    <!-- page content here... -->
  </Grid>

</local:CustomPage>
```

I believe I just don't understand how to qualify the CustomPage type at the root element level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your code-behind file to inherit `CustomPage` too.

Comment: I've done that, but that results in the following compilation error:  Partial declarations of 'MyProject.Page1' must not specify different base classes. The auto-generated Page1.g.cs file conflicts with my code behind.

Comment: My apologies - you were right. I tried a few different things in a mixed up order. Your solution was right.